# Changing case of URL in \href argument

Tags: macros, hyperref, capitalization

I would like to write a macro similar to the `\href` command from the `hyperref` package, but which takes a single argument. The URL is generated by making the argument lowercase.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand\mylink[1]{\href{www.\lowercase{#1}.com}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\mylink{MyURL}
\end{document}
```

However, the `\lowercase` command is not expanded, and the link points to `www.\lowercase{MyURL}.com`. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\newcommand\mylink[1]{\lowercase{\href{www.#1.com}}{#1}}
```

will work.

As requested in comments a more complicated example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand\mylink[1]{\lowercase{\href{www.#1.com}}{#1}}
\newcommand\mymail[2]{%
\lowercase{\def\tmpa{#1}}%
\uppercase{\def\tmpb{#2}}%
\href{mailto:\tmpa.\tmpb}{#1.#2}}

\begin{document}
\mylink{MyURL}

\mymail{David}{Example.ORG}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Do you know any reason why this stops working if I put in my class file rather than the preamble? Or do I need to check for conflicting settings?

Comment: should make no difference unless something else redefines it add `\show\mylink` after `\begin{document}` and tex will stop and show you the definition, if it isn't your definition something else is defining it.

Comment: Apologies - it was a typo that was confusing me. Thanks again for the solution.

Comment: Surprising that it works. But out of curiosity: How to expand stuff in `\href`? I might want to do something like: `\href{mailto:\lowercase{#1}.\uppercase{#2}}{#1.#2}`

Comment: Things expand automatically in `\href`: the problem is that `\lowercase` is not an expandable command, I'll add code to the answer for this

Comment: Some other comments https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513914/hrefurltext-doesnt-open-the-url-in-new-browser#comment1299566_513914 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200577/make-hyperref-links-open-in-new-browser-window-for-easier-navigation/201952#comment466594_200590 claims that `\href` requires initial `http://` or `https://` to work while this answer seems to not put that. Any idea?

Comment: @user202729 this answer lowercased the string requested, whether that string is in fact a valid url that would work in the pdf file was apparently not commened on at the time...  also it assumes a real (ascii) url, `\lowercase` would mess up utf8 in pdftex (probably I should add an expl3 case change answer)