# Provide boolean from two arguments case insensitives

Tags: conditionals, indexing, etoolbox

In most publications scientific names are abbreviated except the first time. Moreover, the names must be in *italics* and only the first letter of the generic name should be upper-case.

The `biocon` package allow define a identifier for each species that manage all these requirements, but I don't want depend of remember a identifier for each species. I want also include a well formatted nested index entry each time in the same step, that manually is a lot of code typing that  obfuscated the body text.

So I decided to make my own macro for this in the form the command `\species{Genus}{species}`. The result is the MWE that worked reasonably,  but I found some problems that seem  related with `etoolbox` package:

1. `\setbool` inside tabulars do not work, failing to switch to the abbreviate name.
2. The arguments are case sensitive, but I cannot reduce all possible occurrences to obtain a unique boolean for each species. I tried `\providebool{\lowercase{#1#2}}` but do not work. This, I can correct case variations in the output but having a different boolean each time, so the macro cannot switch to the abbreviated form, and worse, produce a duplicated index entry.

[image: MWE]
[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{biocon}
\makeindex

% Provide \genus{Generic name}
\newcommand\genus[1]{{\em\lowercase{\protect\makefirstuc{#1}}}
\index{#1@{\em\lowercase{\protect\makefirstuc{#1}}}|textbf}}

% Provide \species{Generic name}{specific name}
\newcommand\species[2]{%
\providebool{#1#2}%
\ifbool{#1#2}%
% abbreviated name
{\emph{\uppercase{\StrLeft{#1}{1}}. \lowercase{#2}}}% 
% full name
{\setbool{#1#2}{true}{\em\lowercase{\protect\makefirstuc{#1} #2}}}%
%index entry for both types
\index{#1@{\em\lowercase{\protect\makefirstuc{#1}}}!#2@{\em\uppercase{\protect\StrLeft{#1}{1}}. \lowercase{#2}}}}


\begin{document}

\noindent Desired ouput of some \genus{Homo} species:\\\\
\species{Homo}{erectus} \texttt{(full name 1st time, OK)}\\
\species{Homo}{erectus} \texttt{(abbreviation 2nd time, OK)}\\
\species{Homo}{sapiens} \texttt{(indexed as Homo!sapiens, OK)}\\
\species{Homo}{erectus} \\ 
\species{Homo}{sapiens} \texttt{(indexed as as Homo!sapiens too, OK)}\\

\noindent Testing in tabular environment:\\\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline\species{Homo}{habilis} & \\
\hline\species{Homo}{habilis} & \texttt{(not working inside tabular)}\\\hline
\end{tabular}\\

\noindent\species{Homo}{habilis} method (try again):\\

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline\species{Homo}{habilis} & \texttt{ 
(\textbackslash{}setbool worked only outside tabular)}\\\hline
\end{tabular}\bigskip

\noindent Testing case correction:\\ 
\verb|\species{Homo}{Antecessor}|: \species{Homo}{Antecessor}\\ 
\verb|\species{Homo}{antecessor}|: \species{Homo}{antecessor}\\
\verb|\species{HOMO}{ANTECEsSOR}|: \species{HOMO}{ANTECEsSOR}\\\\ 
Problems with these three equivalents commands:\\ 
\texttt{not abbreviations}\\
\texttt{duplicated "Homo" at index}\\
\texttt{duplicated "antecessor" at index}\\

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: On the `tabular` issue, put `\global` before `\setbool` in your `\species` definition. On the second problem, you need to fix the case first, then call an internal version of your `\species` command that works on saved versions of the case corrected strings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a hopefully complete solution also to the indexing problems. The assumption is that in the species' names you have only plain ASCII characters.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{biocon}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\makeindex

% Provide \genus{Generic name}
\newcommand\genus[1]{%
  \lowercase{\ifcsname genus@#1\endcsname}\else
    \definnergenus#1\relax
  \fi
  \lowercase{\csname genus@#1\endcsname}%
}
\def\definnergenus#1#2\relax{%
  \def\tempinitial{#1}%
  \lowercase{\def\tempsecond{#2}\def\tempname{#1#2}}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \gdef\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname genus@\tempname\endcsname}{%
      \noexpand\emph{\tempinitial\tempsecond}%
      \noexpand\index{\tempname@{\noexpand\em\tempinitial\tempsecond}|textbf}%
    }%
  }\x}

% Provide \species{Generic name}{specific name}
\newcommand\species[2]{%
  \lowercase{\ifcsname species@#1#2\endcsname\else}%
    \definnerspecies#1\relax{#2}%
  \fi
  \lowercase{\csname species@#1#2\endcsname}%
  \lowercase{\csname speciesindex@#1#2\endcsname}%
}
\def\definnerspecies#1#2\relax#3{%
  \uppercase{\def\tempinitial{#1}}%
  \lowercase{\def\tempfirst{#1}\def\tempsecond{#2}\def\tempthird{#3}}%
  \edef\tempname{\tempfirst\tempsecond\tempthird}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \gdef\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname species@\tempname\endcsname}{%
      \noexpand\emph{\tempinitial\tempsecond\space\tempthird}%
      \gdef\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname species@\tempname\endcsname}{%
        \noexpand\emph{\tempinitial.\ \tempthird}}}}\x
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \gdef\unexpanded\expandafter{\csname speciesindex@\tempname\endcsname}{%
      \noexpand\index{%
        \tempfirst\tempsecond@{\noexpand\em\tempinitial\tempsecond}!%
        \tempthird@{\noexpand\em\tempthird}}%
    }}\x}

\begin{document}

\noindent Desired ouput of some \genus{Homo} species:\\
\\
\species{Homo}{erectus} \texttt{(full name 1st time, OK)}\\
\\
\species{Homo}{erectus} \texttt{(abbreviation 2nd time, OK)}\\
\species{Homo}{sapiens} \texttt{(indexed as Homo!sapiens, OK)}\\
\species{Homo}{erectus} \\ 
\species{Homo}{sapiens} \texttt{(indexed as as Homo!sapiens too, OK)}

\noindent Testing in tabular environment:\\
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline\species{Homo}{habilis} & \\
\hline\species{Homo}{habilis} & \texttt{(works also inside tabular)}\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\noindent\species{Homo}{habilis} method (try again):

\noindent Testing case correction:\\ 
\verb|\species{Homo}{Antecessor}|: \species{Homo}{Antecessor}\\ 
\verb|\species{Homo}{antecessor}|: \species{Homo}{antecessor}\\
\verb|\species{HOMO}{ANTECEsSOR}|: \species{HOMO}{ANTECEsSOR}

\printindex
\end{document}
```

Every `\species` command defines two commands: for instance

```
\species{Homo}{erectus}
```

defines

```
\species@homoerectus
\speciesindex@homoerectus
```

The first one expands to *Homo erectus* and globally redefines itself to expand to *H. erectus*. The input is normalized so that only lowercase letters are used, with the exception of the first initial. The second command deals with the index.

If `\speciec@homoerectus` is undefined (at the first appearance of `\species{Homo}{erectus}`, the `\definespecies` command is called that globally defines the two commands above.

Similarly, `\genus{Homo}` defines, at its first call, an inner macro with normalized input `\genus@homo`, that takes care of printing the name and issuing the indexing command.

Here are the pictures.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow. Some day I will be able to understand this code. However, now is \genus{Homo} which produce a duplicated index entry.

Comment: @Fran Fixed. `:-)`

Comment: Geniale. Just curiosity: What is #2 in \genus and #3 in \species if these commands have only 1 and 2 arguments?

Comment: @Fran The helper command `\definnergenus` and `\definnerspecies` have, respectively, two and three arguments; `#1` is the first letter of the first (or only) argument to `\species` or `\genus`, `#2` the remaining part of this argument; for `\genus`, `#3` is the second argument. You'll have problems if you plan to have `\genus` or `\species` in a section title; in that case you'll have to decide what should happen for the TOC and index, and for the abbreviated form.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. Although [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg) provided  (​​in few minutes!) a complete rewrite of the macro, that works perfectly with the bonus point of not relying in `etoolbook` package, did not solve why `\lowercase` within `\providebool`, like the money inside my wallet, is not expandable.

Like stubborn nobody beats me, I was trying a solution for this specific problem although I have not still knowledge to
use the Dark Side of La(TeX). Providentially, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95662/11604) of David Carlisle put me on the track. This is the result, which seems to work also without problems:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

% Note: ending % neeeded to avoid extra speces

% Provide \species{Generic name}{specific name}
\newcommand\species[2]{%
% expand lowercase https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95662/11604
\lowercase{\def\tmpa{#1#2}}% Identifier 
\lowercase{\def\tmpb{#1}}%   Lower case genus
\lowercase{\def\tmpc{#2}}%   Lower case species
\providebool{\tmpa}%
\ifbool{\tmpa}% 
{\emph{\uppercase{\StrLeft{#1}{1}}.~\tmpc}}% abbreviated name
{\global\setbool{\tmpa}{true}{\em\lowercase{\protect\makefirstuc{#1} #2}}}% full name
\index{\tmpb@{\em\protect\makefirstuc{\tmpb}}!\tmpc@{\em\uppercase{\protect\StrLeft{\tmpb}{1}}. \tmpc}|textsf}}% Index


% Provide \genus{Generic name}
\newcommand\genus[1]{%
\lowercase{\def\tmpb{#1}}% Lower cases genus
{\em\lowercase{\protect\makefirstuc{#1}}}% Genus name
\index{\tmpb@{\em\protect\makefirstuc{\tmpb}}|textbf}} % Index

\begin{document}

Hominoidea as \species{Heliopithecus}{leakeyi} existed about 16 million years ago, but \species{PaN}{TroglodYTES} diverged from  \genus{Homo} genus only about six millions years ago. The \genus{Homo} genus have many extint species as \species{Homo}{AnTecessor}. Problably \species{HOMO}{ANTECESSOR} was a evolutionary link between \species{hOmO}{ErgASter} and \species {Homo}{HEIDELBERGensis}. \species{homo}{Antecessor} is one of the earlist human species.
\newpage
The \genus{Pan}\footnote{Just for testing indexing in footnote, in Spanish \genus{pan} \index{pan (food)|see{bread}} mean "bread"\index{bread}.} actually is composed by \species{pan}{troglodytes} (chimpanzee) and \species{pan}{paniscus} (bonobo\index{bonobo|see{\emph{Pan paniscus}}}). 
species, but \genus{hOMO} is represented only by \species{homo}{sapiens} and \index{Human!Dummy people} people that believe the speeches of politicians.  

\newpage

Cheeta is a fictional character interpreted by several intelligents \species{Pan}{troglodytes} actors whereas Tarzan character was always an \index{hairless} hairless ape-men.   

\printindex
\end{document}
```