# Changing case when writing in auxiliary file

Tags: auxiliary-files

in order to improve reledmac, I would like to write in an auxiliary file, but changing the case when writing in this file.

I have tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
s
\newwrite\sncf
\openout\sncf=sncf.tex

\makeatletter
\expandafter\write\expandafter\sncf\expandafter{\lowercase{TOTO}}
\write\sncf{\lowercase{TOTO}}
\protected@write{\sncf}{}{\lowercase{SNCF}}
\closeout\sncf
\end{document}
```

But,  in the `sncf.tex` I get

```
\lowercase {TOTO}
\lowercase {TOTO}
\lowercase {SNCF}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a little help from David Carlisles answer on [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95660/changing-case-of-url-in-href-argument).

The `\lowercase` changes argument #2 into lowercase letters, before `\@tmp` is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% #1: stream
% #2: text
\newcommand{\WriteAsLowerCase}[2]{%
    \lowercase{\def\@tmp{#2}}%
    \expandafter\write\expandafter#1\expandafter{\@tmp}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
s
\newwrite\sncf
\openout\sncf=sncf.tex
\WriteAsLowerCase{\sncf}{TOTO}
\WriteAsLowerCase{\sncf}{TATA}
\WriteAsLowerCase{\sncf}{SNCF}
\closeout\sncf
\end{document}
```

With this `sncf.tex` looks like this:

```
toto
tata
sncf
```

Remark: without all the `\expandafter`s the text gets converted to lowercase too. But since `\write` is delayed until the next page is shiped out, the last meaning of `\@tmp` would be used. Thus you would get three lines, all containing `sncf`.