# \href{url}{text} doesn't open the url in new browser

Tags: url, href

I have tried to create an url with a text, such that when you click the text, a new browser loads that url. The solution that was offered on this site was the following

```
\href{www.urllink.com}{some text}
```

But when I click the text (some text in this case) it says

File C:\user\myname\ ... \ document_location \ www.urllink.com not found

For some reason, it searches for a file instead of opening the browser and then load the link. I have searched for a solution but couldn't find. Does anybody have any idea what I am doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: the url should be a full url, so start with `https://`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you! That solved my problem! I really appreciate the help